# Как записать в файл timestamp?

Tags: ant

Каким образом можно получить timestamp и записать его в файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте таску [tstamp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tstamp.html) для того, чтобы получить таймсэмп. А таску [echo](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html) с аттрибутом file чтобы писать в файл.